# Get Navigation Filters Programmatically

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, rest-api

I am developing API to get the navigation filters in catalog and search results page.
Using the below code I'm able to get the available filters for a category. I need apply any of the filters to the category and should get the resulted navigation filter. Same this has to be done for search results page also.

```
$categoryId = 3;
        $this->layerResolver->setCurrentCategory($categoryId);
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $fill = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList');
        $filterList = new \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList($objectManager,$fill);
        $filterAttributes = $filterList->getFilters($this->layerResolver);
        $filterArray = array();
        $i = 0;

       foreach($filterAttributes as $filter)
       {
           //$availablefilter = $filter->getRequestVar(); //Gives the request param name such as 'cat' for Category, 'price' for Price
           $availablefilter = (string)$filter->getName(); //Gives Display Name of the filter such as Category,Price etc.
           $items = $filter->getItems(); //Gives all available filter options in that particular filter
           $filterValues = array();
           $j = 0;
           foreach($items as $item)
           {
               $filterValues[$j]['display'] = strip_tags($item->getLabel());
               $filterValues[$j]['label'] = $item->getValue();
               $filterValues[$j]['count'] = $item->getCount(); //Gives no. of products in each filter options
               $j++;
           }
           if(!empty($filterValues))
           {
               $filterArray['availablefilter'][$availablefilter] =  $filterValues;
           }
           $i++;
       }
        return array($filterArray);
```

Is there any possible way to get navigation filters for a product collection so that it will work for both category and search pages.

Comment: Any update on this SIBHI ? i was trying to do the same

Comment: What is the class for $this->layerResolver ?

Comment: @Vignesh Bala injected this class in constructor \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver and assigned the variable as $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver->get();

Comment: But I got the following error. Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-5a9e6a9cd97ec; Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '_idx.entity_id) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`.....

Comment: Try this https://magecom.wordpress.com/page/2/

Comment: I tried the above also but getting same error. I am using Magento 2.1.9 CE

Comment: anyone got the solution ?

Comment: @SIBHIS any update on this?? Could you please share the feedback??

Comment: @gajjala sandeep We have to build the product collection query to satisfy our requirements. In our case we had used elastic search module in desktop. So we used the same collection for our new API also.